# Missing required potential argument in function call Python

Tags: python

I'm just starting to learn Python, and was writing a calculator program with two different files to get the concept of calling classes and functions down. The file with the mathmatical operations in a class looks as such:

```
class standardOpperations:
def __init__(self, primaryNumber, secondaryNumber):
    primaryNumber.self = primaryNumber
    secondaryNumber.self = secondaryNumber
def addition(self, primaryNumber, secondaryNumber):
    print(primaryNumber, "+", secondaryNumber, "=", primaryNumber.self+secondaryNumber)
def subtraction(self, primaryNumber, secondaryNumber):
    print(primaryNumber, "-", secondaryNumber, "=", primaryNumber-secondaryNumber)
def multiplication(self, primaryNumber, secondaryNumber):
    print(primaryNumber, "*", secondaryNumber, "=", primaryNumber * secondaryNumber)
def division(self, primaryNumber, secondaryNumber):
    print(primaryNumber, "/", secondaryNumber, "=", primaryNumber / secondaryNumber)
```

In a separate file, I tried to call this object (specifically the first function) in this line of code:

```
number01 = float(input("Please input a number here: "))
number02 = float(input("Please input a second number here: "))
addObj = standardOpperations.addition(number01,number02)
```

My issue is that upon running it, I get an error stating that I am missing a required potential argument, even though the function only uses two numbers. I'd really appreciate any help I can get in spotting my mistake, and helping the program work. Thanks all!

Comment: hint: you're calling an instance method like a normal function (note the required self argument in instance methods - this self argument is only automatically and implicitly passed as the first argument when called as instance method)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are treating each function as a static method, remove the constructor and the word `self` anywhere in the class.

```
class standardOpperations:

    def addition(primaryNumber, secondaryNumber):
        print(primaryNumber, "+", secondaryNumber, "=", primaryNumber+secondaryNumber)
    def subtraction(primaryNumber, secondaryNumber):
        print(primaryNumber, "-", secondaryNumber, "=", primaryNumber-secondaryNumber)
    def multiplication(primaryNumber, secondaryNumber):
        print(primaryNumber, "*", secondaryNumber, "=", primaryNumber * secondaryNumber)
    def division(primaryNumber, secondaryNumber):
        print(primaryNumber, "/", secondaryNumber, "=", primaryNumber / secondaryNumber)


>>> standardOpperations.addition(1,2)
1 + 2 = 3
```

Comment: Thanks! That solved my problem. Now I have to ask though, what does the init function do for a function? I was taught to use that whenever I made a function in class, but there are evidently places where it shouldn't be used. Is there a specific purpose it is typically used for? Thank you again for helping me solve my issue

Answer (score 1):

I have corrected your code.

Please find the working code below

```
class standardOpperations:
  def __init__(self, primaryNumber, secondaryNumber):
      self.primaryNumber = primaryNumber
      self.secondaryNumber = secondaryNumber
  def addition(self):
      print(self.primaryNumber, "+", self.secondaryNumber, "=", self.primaryNumber+self.secondaryNumber)
  def subtraction(self):
      print(self.primaryNumber, "-", self.secondaryNumber, "=", self.primaryNumber-self.secondaryNumber)
  def multiplication(self):
      print(self.primaryNumber, "*", self.secondaryNumber, "=", self.primaryNumber * self.secondaryNumber)
  def division(self):
      print(self.secondaryNumber, "=", self.primaryNumber / self.secondaryNumber)
```

```
number01 = float(input("Please input a number here: "))
number02 = float(input("Please input a second number here: "))
addObj = standardOpperations(number01,number02)
addObj.addition()
```